# How to remove Applications Menu GNOME Extension?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, uninstall, gnome-shell-extension, extension

The Applications Menu GNOME Extension doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04. Applications menu on the top bar is inactive and can not be removed (in obvious way) even after uninstall.

Main problem is that the unresponsive Applications text/button does not disappear after uninstalling the extension.

**It seems I am not the only one struggling with this issue:**

Review from user damir107:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6/applications-menu/

Also turning on hot corners doesn't change anything for me.

Any idea how to remove the text/button from the top left corner? Thanks!

Comment: how did you install and uninstall this extension ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had this problem, and stumbled upon this question while trying to find out how to remove it. Finally I did.

RUN:

```
cd /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions
sudo rm -rf apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
```

Reboot after.

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly. I tried the same before but in an other location: /home/USERNAME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions but this did nothing.

Comment: hunyi's .local one worked for me  20.04.1